# GStreamer RTP full-duplex video in/out with single rtpbin

Tags: gstreamer, duplex

I'm trying to create gstreamer pipeline with rtpbin to stream webcam both way (videophone). However, I am not even able to make rtpbin work with simple snippet like below which just takes webcam source and streams out, then other udpsrc captures RTP packets and displays. All localhost. When splitted to two pipes and launched separately, it works. This, however, not. I  feel it has something with threading, however I am stucked here as no queue worked for me so far.
Basically, what I need is displaying incomming videostream and stream out my webcam videostream out to remote party.

gst-launch -v \
gstrtpbin name=rtpbin \
udpsrc caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H263" port=5000 ! rtpbin. \
rtpbin. ! rtph263depay ! ffdec_h263 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink \
v4l2src ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=30/1, width=320, height=240 ! videoscale ! videorate ! "video/x-raw-yuv,width=352,height=288,framerate=30/1" ! ffenc_h263 ! rtph263pay ! rtpbin. \
rtpbin. ! udpsink port=5000

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I have to answer to myself, it was enough to add sync=false async=false to the udpsink:

gst-launch -v \
gstrtpbin name=rtpbin udpsrc caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H263" port=5000 ! queue ! rtpbin. \
rtpbin. ! rtph263depay ! ffdec_h263 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink \
v4l2src ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=30/1, width=320, height=240 ! videoscale ! videorate ! "video/x-raw-yuv,width=352,height=288,framerate=30/1" ! ffenc_h263 ! rtph263pay ! rtpbin. \
rtpbin. ! udpsink port=5000 **sync=false async=false**

Comment: as per documentation: "When the element is set to PLAYING, GstBaseSink will synchronise on the clock using the times returned from GstBaseSinkClass.get_times(). If this function returns GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE for the start time, no synchronisation will be done. Synchronisation can be disabled entirely by setting the object "sync" property to FALSE." I have no idea what it wanted synchronize to when sync and async wasn't in place.